building a WSDL using PeopleCode with a built CI (Component Interface)
I'm trying to build a WSDL using PeopleCode using a built CI which looked like this
import PS_PT:Integration:IRequestHandler;

class N_STDNT_PERSONAL_INFO implements PS_PT:Integration:IRequestHandler
   method N_STDNT_PERSONAL_INFO();
   method OnRequest(&MSG As Message) Returns Message;
end-class;

/* constructor */
method N_STDNT_PERSONAL_INFO
end-method;



method OnRequest
   /+ &MSG as Message +/
   /+ Returns Message +/
   /+ Extends/implements PS_PT:Integration:IRequestHandler.OnRequest +/
   /* Variable Declaration */
   Local Message &msgResp;
   Local Document &docReq, &docResp;
   Local Compound &compReq, &compResp, &detailData, &detailPhone;
   Local Collection &itemData, &itemPhone;
   Local number &I, &legendNumber;
   Local string &strBinusianID, &strStudentName;
   Local string &strPhoneType, &strPhoneNbr, &strPref;
   Local string &strChkBinusian, &strGetPhone;
   Local string &legendDtl1, &legendDtl2, &legendDtl3, &legendDtl4, &legendDtl5, &legendDtl6, &legendDtl7, &legendDtl8, &legendDtl9, &legendDtl10;
   Local SQL &sql01;
   Local any &nRet;
   Local ApiObject &oSession, &oUpdatePhoneCI, &oUpdatePhoneDtlCollection, &oUpdatePhoneDtl;
   Local array of string &arrPhoneNbr, &arrPhoneType, &arrPref, &arrCountryCode;
   Local boolean &foundCellPhone;
   Local ApiObject &oNPhonePers;
   Local ApiObject &oSccPersPhnHCollection, &oSccPersPhnH;
   
   /* Create response message */
   &msgResp = CreateMessage(Operation.N_STDNT_PERSONAL_INFO, %IntBroker_Response);
   &docResp = &msgResp.GetDocument();
   &compResp = &docResp.DocumentElement;
   
   /* get the body of the incoming message */
   /* get input parameters from request */
   &docReq = &MSG.GetDocument();
   &compReq = &docReq.DocumentElement;
   
   &strBinusianID = &compReq.GetPropertyByName("BinusianID").Value;
   &legendNumber = &compReq.GetPropertyByName("LegendNumber").Value;
   
   try
      If None(&strBinusianID) Or
            None(&legendNumber) Or
            &legendNumber < 1 Or
            &legendNumber > 25 Or
            Not IsNumber(&legendNumber) Then
         throw CreateException(0, 0, "01");
      
      &itemData = &compReq.GetPropertyByName("ItemData");
      &detailData = &itemData.GetItem(1);
      &legendDtl1 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend1").Value;
      &legendDtl2 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend2").Value;
      &legendDtl3 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend3").Value;
      &legendDtl4 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend4").Value;
      &legendDtl5 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend5").Value;
      &legendDtl6 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend6").Value;
      &legendDtl7 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend7").Value;
      &legendDtl8 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend8").Value;
      &legendDtl9 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend9").Value;
      &legendDtl10 = &detailData.GetPropertyByName("Legend10").Value;
      
      If &legendNumber = 1 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "02");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 2 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "03");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 3 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl3) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "04");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 4 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "05");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 5 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "06");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 6 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "07");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 7 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl3) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "08");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 8 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Or
               None(&legendDtl3) Or
               None(&legendDtl4) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl4 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl5 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl5) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "09");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 9 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Or
               None(&legendDtl3) Or
               None(&legendDtl4) Or
               None(&legendDtl5) Or
               None(&legendDtl6) Or
               None(&legendDtl7) Or
               None(&legendDtl8) Or
               None(&legendDtl9) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl4 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl5 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl6 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl7 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl8 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl9 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl10 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl10) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "10");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 10 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "11");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 11 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "12");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 12 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "13");
            /*Else
            &arrPhoneNbr.Push(&legendDtl1);
            &arrPhoneType.Push(&legendDtl2);
            &arrPref.Push(&legendDtl3);*/
         End-If;
         
         
         rem Local File &fileLog;
         
         
         
         
         try
            &oSession = %Session;
            
            &oSession.PSMessagesMode = 1;
            
            rem ***** Get the Component Interface *****;
            &oNPhonePers = &oSession.GetCompIntfc(CompIntfc.N_PHONE_PERS);
            If &oNPhonePers = Null Then
               throw CreateException(0, 0, "GetCompIntfc failed");
            End-If;
            
            rem ***** Set the Component Interface Mode *****;
            &oNPhonePers.InteractiveMode = False;
            &oNPhonePers.GetHistoryItems = True;
            &oNPhonePers.EditHistoryItems = True;
            
            rem ***** Set Component Interface Get/Create Keys *****;
            &oNPhonePers.EMPLID = &strBinusianID;
            
            rem ***** Execute Get *****;
            If Not &oNPhonePers.Get() Then
               rem ***** No rows exist for the specified keys.*****;
               
               throw CreateException(0, 0, "Get failed");
            End-If;
            
            
            rem ***** Begin: Get/Set Component Interface Properties *****;
            
            rem ***** Set/Get SCC_PERS_PHN_H Collection Field Properties -- Parent: PS_ROOT Collection *****;
            &oSccPersPhnHCollection = &oNPhonePers.SCC_PERS_PHN_H;
            Local integer &i17;
            For &i17 = 1 To &oSccPersPhnHCollection.Count;
               &oSccPersPhnH = &oSccPersPhnHCollection.Item(&i17);
               &oSccPersPhnH.PHONE_TYPE = &legendDtl1;
               &oSccPersPhnH.PHONE = &legendDtl2;
               &oSccPersPhnH.PREF_PHONE_FLAG = &legendDtl3;
            End-For;
            rem ***** End: Get/Set Component Interface Properties *****;
            
            rem ***** Execute Save *****;
            If Not &oNPhonePers.Save() Then
               throw CreateException(0, 0, "Save failed");
            End-If;
            
            rem ***** Execute Cancel *****;
            rem If Not &oNPhonePers.Cancel() Then;
            rem     errorHandler();
            rem     throw CreateException(0, 0, "Cancel failed");
            rem End-If;
            
            rem ***** Execute Delete *****;
            rem &[*] = &oNPhonePers.Delete([*]);
         catch Exception &ex1
            rem Handle the exception;
            rem &fileLog.WriteLine(&ex1.ToString());
         end-try;
         rem &fileLog.WriteLine("End");
         rem &fileLog.Close();
         
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 13 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Or
               None(&legendDtl3) Or
               None(&legendDtl4) Or
               None(&legendDtl5) Or
               None(&legendDtl6) Or
               None(&legendDtl7) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl4 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl5 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl6 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl7 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "14");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 14 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl3) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "15");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 15 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl3) Or
               &legendDtl4 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl4) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "16");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 16 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl3) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "17");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 17 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Or
               None(&legendDtl3) Or
               None(&legendDtl4) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl3 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl4 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl5 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl5) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "18");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 18 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "19");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 19 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "20");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 20 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "21");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 21 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "22");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 22 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "23");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 23 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "24");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 24 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Or
               &legendDtl2 = "?" Or
               None(&legendDtl2) Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "25");
         End-If;
      End-If;
      If &legendNumber = 25 Then
         If None(&legendDtl1) Or
               &legendDtl1 = "?" Then
            throw CreateException(0, 0, "26");
         End-If;
      End-If;
   
      
      &compResp.GetPropertyByName("RespStatus").Value = "00";
      &compResp.GetPropertyByName("StatusDetail").Value = "Success";
      
   catch Exception &ex
      &compResp.GetPropertyByName("RespStatus").Value = Left(&ex.DefaultText, 2);
      &compResp.GetPropertyByName("StatusDetail").Value = Left(&ex.ToString(), 200);
   end-try;
   Return &msgResp;
end-method;


I tried updating the data which returned success but nothing changed in the query
enter image description hereenter image description here
my question:

any reason why this is happening and how do I fix this?
if in the wsdl I put more than one phone number, is there anything more I need to do in the code?

if it returns success, the database should be updated based on the picture of the wsdl but it's not updated
